# Why is combineLatest not triggering inside switchMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am constructing an observable which can be used in angular template using async operator. This observable is formed using following structure

```
combineLatest(2 observables) ---> switchMap( combineLatest(2 observables)
```

But my inner combine latest only gets triggered when I get response from both the APIs. Is there anything incorrect that I am doing?

```
private searchUsersAndGroups(): void {
this.displayedList$ = combineLatest([this.searchText$, this.dataPartitionAccountId$]).pipe(
  filter(([searchText, dataPartitionAccountId]) => {
    return !!searchText && !!searchText.trim() && !!dataPartitionAccountId;
  }),
  tap((values) => {
    console.log(values);
  }),
  switchMap(([searchText, dataPartitionAccountId]) => {
    console.log('selectedUsers', this.selectedUsers);

    const users$ = this.userSearchService
      .getUserList({
        searchText: searchText.trim(),
        accountId: dataPartitionAccountId
      })
      .pipe(
        startWith([]),
        map((users) => {
          return users;
        }),
        catchError(() => [])
      );

    const groups$ = this.userSearchService
      .getGroupList({
        accountId: dataPartitionAccountId
      })
      .pipe(
        startWith([]),
        mergeMap((groups: DisplaySearchInfo[]) => groups),
        filter((group: DisplaySearchInfo) => {
          return (
            group.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            group.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            group.createdBy.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
          );
        }),
        catchError(() => [])
      );

    return combineLatest([users$, groups$]).pipe(
      map((values) => {
        console.log('############ ', values[0]);
        console.log('************ ', values[1]);
        return values;
      })
     );
    })
  )}
```

is the startWith a culprit?

Comment: combineLatest doesn’t emit until all observables emit at least once and startWith should be last in the pipe stream to emit straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my inner combine latest only gets triggered when I get response from both the APIs.

This is the intended behaviour of `combineLatest` operator.

From [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) docs,

> To ensure the output array always has the same length, combineLatest will actually wait for all input Observables to emit at least once, before it starts emitting results.